# Interface type of refence running the child class method which is not defined in the interface

Tags: java

I've a code:

```
interface My {
    //this is left empty
}

class Test implements My {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        My m=new Test();
        String str=m.toString();    //how reference variable m calls toString() in Test even it is not in My?
        System.out.println(str);
        str=m.show();    //Error:
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Hello";
    }

    public String show(){
        return "World";
    }
}
```

The error at `str=m.show()` is `cannot find symbol str=m.show()` and `location: variable m of type My`.

My question is how the `m.toString()` does not report any error but `m.show()` report such error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toString()` is defined in `Object`. Any concrete implementation of an interface will also extend `Object`, so you can call any method declared in `Object`.

Comment: but in `Object` class `toString()` must be having a body and all i know is that you can not give body to any method inside an interface

Comment: Yes, but an interface is not a concrete implementation. In order to reference an interface, some **`Object`** must provide a concrete implementation.

Comment: you are saying interface extends `Object` which is a class. can i extend an interface with my own class?

Comment: I'm saying that any implementation of an interface occurs in an `Object`. Since any implementation must occur in an `Object` you can access any of `Object`'s methods. You can extend interfaces with other interfaces.

Comment: but what about class? can i extend an interface with my own class?

Comment: A class may implement interfaces, but not extend them.

Comment: i'm not understanding `any implementation of an interface occurs in an Object`. Did you have any link or please describe it clearly. please!

Comment: In your example: `class Test implements My` could be rewritten as `class Test extends Object implements My`. In order to reference an interface, it must be implemented. You can only implement an interface in an object.

Comment: suppose if i'd another class `Example` and i rewrite my program as `class Test extends Example implements My` then where is `My` interface is actually implementing and how?

Comment: `My` is implemented in `Test`. When you implement an interface, you are just implementing every abstract method contained in the interface. But since `Test extends Example`, and `Example extends Object`, `Test` still has all the methods of an Object.

Answer (score 1):

The [toString](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method is defined in the [Object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class which all objects derive from including `Test`. So every instance of an object in Java has this method. You can override it in a derived class `Test` and this method will be invoked instead of the base one.

As far as the other error message is concerned about the `show` method, the type of the `m` variable is the `My` interface and there is no such method defined inside this interface.

Comment: please check the answer by Jeffrey and help me understand the actual logic

Answer (score 0):

The toString method is a method of class Object, hence all Java objects have toString. Your object m is declared with type My, and interface My does not have a method called "show"